# Reading the Json string which is put together in one field

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, unix, informatica

I have a Json pattern string in a text file, I have to pharse the below string like below and put it in to a external file.

Please let me know how this can be handled with Informatica Powercenter or Unix or Python?

{"CONTACTID":"3b2a25b2","ANI":"+16146748702","DNIS":"+18006081123","START_TIME":"01/22/2023 03:31:42","MODULE":[{"Name":"MainIVR","Time":"01/22/2023 03:31:42",Dialog":[{"name":"offer_Spanish","dialogeresult":"(|raw:7|R|7|1.0|nm=0|ni=0|2023/22/21 03:02:01)"}],"backend":[{"Time":"01/22/2023)"}],"END_STATE":"XC"}

In The above sample string the special charcters should be removed and the values should be assigned to the corresponding columns like below 2 o/p formats

Output:

CONTACTID,   ANI,      DNIS,      START_TIME,          MODULE,     Time,Dialog,dialogeresult,END_STATE
3b2a25b2,+16146748702 +18006081123 01/22/2023 03:31:42,Name:MainIVR,

or

Output:
CONTACTID : 3b2a25b2
ANI:16146748702
DNI :+18006081123

I tried this to read thru Informatica powercenter and using the expression tranformations but nothing worked and tried with Python too.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your JSON is invalid. The opening double quotes for `Dialog` are missing and it's not properly closed - `MODULE` array is not closed and root is not closed. Here's the fixed JSON:

```
{"CONTACTID":"3b2a25b2","ANI":"+16146748702","DNIS":"+18006081123","START_TIME":"01/22/2023 03:31:42","MODULE":[{"Name":"MainIVR","Time":"01/22/2023 03:31:42","Dialog":[{"name":"offer_Spanish","dialogeresult":"(|raw:7|R|7|1.0|nm=0|ni=0|2023/22/21 03:02:01)"}],"backend":[{"Time":"01/22/2023)"}],"END_STATE":"XC"}]}
```

Use some JSON validation tool, like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) - it helps a lot.

Next, here's some starter code you may use to achieve the required result:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x = '{"CONTACTID":"3b2a25b2","ANI":"+16146748702","DNIS":"+18006081123","START_TIME":"01/22/2023 03:31:42","MODULE":[{"Name":"MainIVR","Time":"01/22/2023 03:31:42","Dialog":[{"name":"offer_Spanish","dialogeresult":"(|raw:7|R|7|1.0|nm=0|ni=0|2023/22/21 03:02:01)"}],"backend":[{"Time":"01/22/2023)"}],"END_STATE":"XC"}]}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y.keys())
```

You may test it on [Replit](https://replit.com/languages/python3)

Finally regarding Informatica Powercenter - it is a terrible choice for complex string processing. You would need a `Hierarchy Parser Transformation`. Long story short: it's very tedious, but possible. I would highly recommend picking up a differen approach, if this is not a regular data loading process you will need to build.

Comment: Thanks fpr your response and also your recommendation, acctyally I couldn't put the complete string since it's huge however I tried the above Python code passing actual string but I am getting the partial o/p like below